# Excel TRIM Function Bug

Tags: excel

TRIM does not appear to work correctly, per the example worksheet attached, or am I misunderstanding it?
Either way, very frustrating for me at the moment as I have a spreadsheet that I have to count the number of words in cells for, and due to this issue, I cannot establish a fully working/robust formula or VBA User Defined Function to achieve this.

I've searched all around the web and not found a solution.

The link below for an excel worksheet that I've shared via dropbox that illustrates the problem.

[Example Worksheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dapo998jxfdaeny/Excel-TRIM-4SO.xlsx?dl=0)

After clicking the link, you should see in your browser, the option to Open With, and be able to choose Microsoft Excel Online, and this will allow you to see what I have already in place, edit etc.

Here is a screen grab of the spreadsheet, and you can see the cells where the number returned seems to be wrong, as it does not match the number of leading/trailing/surplus spaces that are present, as noted on row 10.

Baically, I would expect the numbers on row 13 to match those on row 10.

Those on row 13 are generated by the formula... =LEN(F9)-LEN(TRIM(F9))

Each line of the text in F9 starts with a space and ends with a space, before the line breaks that terminate the first two lines.

@z32a7ul... Thank you, for your info below that is really helpful.

 I had tried something similar but it basically looked like this...

 =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1(CHAR(10)," ",""))

 And of course I see now that "" was then obviously not counted as a Space.

 Aaggghhh. I was so close!

[image]

Comment: Please at least describe the bug in your question: i.e. what inputs and formula(s) are you using, what result do you expect to get, what are you actually getting instead? I doubt most people are willing to download and study a random worksheet just to figure out what your problem is. Also, the point of Stack Overflow is to collect answers to common problems so that people can find them on Google; if you don't describe your problem in words, there's no way anyone else with the same problem can possibly find it.

Comment: ... You might also find our help page on creating a [mcve] helpful; while it's written mostly with conventional programming languages in mind, the general principles apply just as well to Excel worksheets too.

Comment: Added more info and a screen capture that will hopefully help to illustrate the problem. The worksheet provides a minimal reprodicible example, that is clearly visible in the image, where cell F13 should return 6 as opposed to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Excel's TRIM treats line feed (ascii 10) as a character inside a word.

If you don't like this, remove them before applying TRIM. You can remove them by substituting them with a space (ascii 32) character.

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," "))
```

Comment: More specifically,  Trim processes only spaces (char(32)), not "whitespace".  So yes, if you want Trim to process general  whitespace characters, you need to replace them with spaces.  The list of such characteristics is quite long...

Comment: Thanks to @z32a7ul for the info/feedback/solution provided.

Comment: Thanks to @chris neilsen for the info/feedback/solution provided.